# Как распарсить API Github на PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, github

Всем привет. Пытаюсь вывести на сайт список релизов репозитория через API Github.

```
$url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/modxcms/revolution/tags';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$releases = json_decode($json);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($releases);
echo '</pre>';
```

выводит NULL

если пройти по ссылке https://api.github.com/repos/modxcms/revolution/tags видно что есть JSON. Нужно получить массив с данными. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/repos/modxcms/revolution/tags): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: как мне кажется, проще всего воспользоваться готовой библиотекой, например, вот этой https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api

либо можете посмотреть как в ней реализованы запросы